# purely theoretical linear algebra textbook with lots of proofs?

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am an advanced undergrad in computer science/statistics. Is there a linear algebra textbook that covers determinants, eigenvalues&eigenvectors, transpose, vector spaces, etc.. and tries to proof them? I have an applied book, and would like a theory based one. The other threads are over 6-9+ years old and I just wanted to see if any more recent texts have come out since.

A great example of what i'm looking for can be found in Casella&Berger's classic textbook on theoretical statistics, Statistical Inference, where they attempt to teach Stats through slowly building a toolbox starting with axioms and then forming theorems from them.

I am a big fan of starting small and building big in textbooks. At first, I thought Axler would be the right approach, but considering how hard some of the older threads came down on the book, I may as well ask for mroe suggestions.

Comment: You don’t need a “more recent textbook”. What you are asking about is the classic theory of linear algebra, and the only thing that a new textbook would have that one from 9 years ago wouldn’t would be pointers to computer software, which is specifically what you don’t want. This is mathematics, not CS: things don’t move so quickly that a 9-year-old textbook in a classic subject would be obsolete.

Comment: I'm personally a big fan of Axler's book; I'm not sure what the problem others have with it. Its main premise is exactly what you described: a ground up approach, mostly pure focus, and ends on the lofty heights of determinant theorems (powerful, but not exactly elementary). I don't know what the other threads said about Axler, but I think it could be a good fit.

Comment: what you are asking for is just any linear algebra textbook for mathematicians. There are a lot of them, starting by the famous book of Halmos. Also I will recommend Axler's book.

Comment: Finite-dimensional vector space by Paul Halmos.

Comment: @user744868 See the point that you made is the issue that the previous threads had. They said that the book ended on determinants and strongly avoided them throughout.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin You've got a point there! I just wanted to know if feelings over certain texts have changed over time. I think I may be picking either Hoffman&Kunze or Halmos. Leaning towards the former.

Comment: Axler doesn't "end" on determinants, so much as it largely builds towards them. Determinants are tricky beasts. It's not really possible to introduce them in any way that makes them intuitive, without spending a full book building them up. Other books tend to hand-wave away the details, and introduce them as a magic black box that does linear algebra for you. That doesn't sound like what you want, which is why I would suggest Axler.

Comment: @user744868 I remember their use in my calc-based physics course and I couldn't have described their usage in that course better. I think I'm going to give the first chapter of each book a try and see which is the one I most want to stick with. Axler sounds like something I'd be interested in.

Comment: I'll recommend *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* by Sergei Treil. It is available freely on his website: http://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html

Comment: I like Freidberg,Insel Spence (the book I studied in lots of detail for my course), but I also like Hoffman and Kunze. These are some classic books. (even Loomis and Sternberg's "Advanced Calculus" book chapter 1,2 is about linear algebra, and it is a very rigorous introduction to vector space theory... although they only focus on the case where the underlying field is $\Bbb{R}$; I read this after I had already had a course in linear algebra, and I think the proofs in there are pretty slick)